# How to fake an audio card Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: sound, xfce, xvfb

I am trying to create a minimum required setup to run an app with GUI that uses Java (already included in the install) on 18.04 cloud server.

I installed `Xvfb` + `X11vnc` and launch the app without problems.

However, when I am in GUI and go into a menu that has sound setting, app freezes. It also freezes if I believe something calls for a sound (even if sound events turned off).

I tried to google and install some audio packages. Did not help.

Weird thing is when I install `xfce4`, my app starts working through those menus. I don't even use xfce, just installed it.

This makes me think there must be some kind of a package or configuration it does that aids my app to run.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar app to yours and I also had problems with sound. Actually, based on my experience xfce4 and mate are the best choices for minimal setup with VNC like this. Currently I use mate.

To build such envoirement from scratch I use following packages:

```
sudo apt install mate-desktop xorg xserver-xorg tightvncserver mate-desktop-environment mplayer pavucontrol alsa-utils alsa-oss pulseaudio
```

When it comes to sound you can see following packages used:

- pavucontrol
- pulseaudio
- alsa-utils
- alsa-oss

With pavucontrol you can disable sound device easily or switch them to something like null output.

And why it works with xfce4 is probably thanks to `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin`.

For VNC I prefer `tightvncserver`.

You need to properly set `~/.vnc/xstartup` though:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
vncconfig -iconic &
mate-session &
```

Then you can start VNC like so:

```
tightvncserver :1
```

Try it out.